# Maximum electrical outlets in room

Tags: electrical

I'm working on a rebuild of my office. I have a number of low-power devices (e.g laptop, musical keyboard, monitor, internet router, etc) which are plugged into extension cords and then fixed to the wall; there are three of these, taking my six outlets (three locations, one double outlet in each) up to 12 outlets.

As part of the rebuild, I would like to get rid of the extension cords, and just have 12 wall outlets.

Is this possible/legal to have this many on a 15amp circuit? Anything I should be aware of?

Located in Utah, USA, if that becomes relevant.

Comment: No kidding. I have so many hard drives and USB blocks plugged into my little Ikea computer hutch on rollers, I'm about to dismount the 9-outlet Belkin strip I mounted on it, and fit three 3-gang metal boxes and a whole-house surge. 18 should do it lol.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, generally speaking you can have as many receptacles as you want on a circuit. There are limitations in some jurisdictions, but 12 - which is really 6 x duplex - is not very many and is unlikely to be a problem.

There are limitations on splitting circuits across multiple rooms, generally when kitchens or bathrooms are involved. But most other rooms have no restrictions.

A few things to keep in mind:

- Total power consumption. Obviously, you already have this under control. When it is practical (relatively easy to run another circuit, panel space available), running an *additional* circuit is often better, as it allows higher total power consumption. That is not an issue for *most* consumer electronics, but if you plan to add a laser printer or any other high power devices then an additional circuit may be helpful.
- Surge protection. I always recommend putting all high value electronics on a good quality surge protector. While there are 1 & 2 receptacle surge protectors available, most common are larger surge protectors - typically 5 to 8 receptacles. That can help a lot in terms of "where to plug everything in". That being said, more receptacles are still often better, particularly if they are spaced in more useful locations.

Comment: There are nice 4 outlet surge protector included receptacles available - they are even set up so you can generally plug in 4 wall warts, rather than like normal double-duplex outlets, and you get to not have all those plug in protectors lying around.

Comment: I usually see it as 12x duplex receps.  They generally count any receptacle product as one.  For instance one of those long Wiremold outlet strips that is 12' long and has 20 outlets on it... one receptacle lol.

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica That's what I'm trying to say, I think. OP is talking about "six outlets" = "three locations, one double in each" and doubling up that to 12 "wall outlets" I think OP really means 6 duplex.

Comment: @manassehkatz-Moving 2 Codidact Correct - I did mean 6 duplex. Thanks